# Telegram bot : Button text is not readable

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram

I have developed telegram bot which responds to users input.But when bot send buttons to user, text of the button is not readable.

Below is the screenshot of chat:
[image]

I think telegram does not resize button when number of buttons are more or button text length is more.

I am using below code to send buttons:

```
buttonoptions.forEach(buttonElement => {

    var buttonText = buttonElement;
    if (buttonText.length > 30) {
        buttonText = buttonText.substring(0, 27);
        buttonText = buttonText + "...";
    }

    var buttonItem = {
        text: buttonText,
        callback_data: JSON.stringify({
            'type': 'button',
            'text': buttonText
        })
    }

    buttons.push(buttonItem);
});

var message = {
    parse_mode: 'Markdown',
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        inline_keyboard: [buttons]
    })
};

//send message code
```

So is there any way to force telegram bot to show complete text of button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telegram Bot API takes **an array of arrays of buttons** as a value of `inline_keyboard` field. Every array represents a row of buttons in inline keyboard.

So, you have many buttons on the same row, the text looks truncated. To avoid this you can place buttons on several rows.

E.g.:

```
const options = {
  reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
      inline_keyboard: [
          [{ text: 'Button 1', callback_data: '1' }],
          [{ text: 'Button 2', callback_data: 'data 2' }],
          [{ text: 'Button 3', callback_data: 'text 3' }]
      ]
   })
};
```

This results in three rows with single button on each. I believe the text will not be truncated.

Cheers!